# awk substitution ascii table rules bash

Tags: bash, awk

I want to perform a hierarchical set of (non-recursive) substitutions in a text file.
I want to define the rules in an ascii file "table.txt" which contains lines of blank space tabulated pairs of strings:

```
aaa 3
aa 2
a 1
```

I have tried to solve it with an awk script "substitute.awk":

```
BEGIN { while (getline < file) { subs[$1]=$2; } }
  { line=$0; for(i in subs) 
              { gsub(i,subs[i],line); } 
             print line; 
  }
```

When I call the script giving it the string "aaa":

```
echo aaa | awk -v file="table.txt" -f substitute.awk
```

I get

```
21
```

instead of the desired "3". Permuting the lines in "table.txt" doesn't help. Who can explain what the problem is here, and how to circumvent it? (This is a simplified version of my actual task. Where I have a large file containing ascii encoded phonetic symbols which I want to convert into Latex code. The ascii encoding of the symbols contains {$,&,-,%,[a-z],[0-9],...)).

Any comments and suggestions!

PS:

Of course in this application for a substitution table.txt:

```
aa ab
a  1
```

a original string: "aa" should be converted into "ab" and not "1b". That means a string which was yielded by applying a rule must be left untouched.

How to account for that?

Answer (score 3):

The order of the loop `for (i in subs)` is undefined by default.

In newer versions of `awk` you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to control the sort order. See section [`12.2.1 Controlling Array Traversal`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) and (the linked) section [`8.1.6 Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) for details about that.

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to do that you could store the replacements in numerically indexed entries in `subs` and walk the array in order manually.

To do that you will need to store both the pattern and the replacement in the value of the array and that will require some care to combine. You can consider using `SUBSEP` or any other character that cannot be in the pattern or replacement and then `split` the value to get the pattern and replacement in the loop.

Also note the caveats/etcץ with `getline` listed on http://awk.info/?tip/getline and consider not using that manually but instead using `NR==1{...}` and just listing `table.txt` as the first file argument to `awk`.

Edit: Actually, for the manual loop version you could also just keep two arrays one mapping input file line number to the patterns to match and another mapping patterns to replacements. Then looping over the line number array will get you the pattern and the pattern can be used in the second array to get the replacement (for `gsub`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am struggling a bit with the implementation. Could you please give some lines of code using PROCINFO?

Comment: `PROCINFO` is an array, you just set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to whatever value you want the `in` loop to use for ordering. One of `"@val_str_asc"` or `"@val_str_desc"` might do what you want but will not get you input file line ordering. For that you likely need to loop manually.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the replacements in an associative array, put them in two arrays indexed by integer (one array for the strings to replace, one for the replacements) and iterate over the arrays in order:

```
BEGIN {i=0; while (getline < file) { subs[i]=$1; repl[i++]=$2} 
  n = i}
  { for(i=0;i<n;i++) { gsub(subs[i],repl[i]); } 
     print tolower($0); 
  }
```

Comment: Now it works perfectly! I already roughly got the message also from what Etan Reisner wrote, but I was not sure how to implement it exactly. So summarizing: When I do everything the same way as I stated, except the awk script, for that one I use yours, then it works. Eg giving "331" for "aaaaaaa". (unfortunately I yet haven't got enough credits to rate your answer, yet, sorry).

Comment: I turns out I have to escape . in the from patterns to \. Is there simple way to avoid this? There is a whole bunch of more special characters to be expected in both the from and to patterns.

Comment: @DarOrko no, you cannot do this job with *sub() as they work on regexps just like sed does.

Comment: Yeah, seams true, I already struggled over some double substituion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like perl's zero-width word boundary is what you want.  It's a pretty straightforward conversion from the awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %subs;
BEGIN{
    open my $f, '<', 'table.txt' or die "table.txt:$!";
    while(<$f>) {
        my ($k,$v) = split;
        $subs{$k}=$v;
    }
}
while(<>) {
  while(my($k, $v) = each %subs) {
    s/\b$k\b/$v/g;
  }
  print;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but when I give "aaaa" to that it returns "aaaa", instead of "31".

Comment: If you don't want to match word boundaries at the end, try removing the `\b` and use `s/\b$k/$v/g`

Comment: William Pursel, unfortunately none of the two scripts work as I expect it. I expect all rules to be applied as often as possible, but after each match in the sequence they are listed in 'table.txt'. So "aaaa" should get 31. But instead you perl script doesn't match "aaaa" at all. It returns "aaaa".

Comment: Instead of storing the replacements in an associative array, put them in two arrays indexed by integer (one array for the strings to replace, one for the replacements) and iterate over the arrays in order.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer pulled from another StackExchange site, from a fairly similar question: [Replace multiple strings in a single pass](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137932/24557).

It's slightly different in that it does the replacements in inverse order by length of target string (i.e. longest target first), but that is the only sensible order for targets which are literal strings, as appears to be the case in this question as well.

If you have [`tcc`](http://www.tinycc.org/) installed, you can use the following shell function, which process the file of substitutions into a `lex`-generated scanner which it then compiles and runs using tcc's compile-and-run option.

```
# Call this as: substitute replacements.txt < text_to_be_substituted.txt
# Requires GNU sed because I was too lazy to write a BRE
substitute () { 
  tcc -run <(
  {
    printf %s\\n "%option 8bit noyywrap nounput" "%%"
    sed -r 's/((\\\\)*)(\\?)$/\1\3\3/;
            s/((\\\\)*)\\?"/\1\\"/g;
            s/^((\\.|[^[:space:]])+)[[:space:]]*(.*)/"\1" {fputs("\3",yyout);}/' \
        "$1"
    printf %s\\n "%%" "int main(int argc, char** argv) { return yylex(); }"
  } | lex -t)
}
```

With `gcc` or `clang`, you can use something similar to compile a substitution program from the replacement list, and then execute that program on the given text. Posix-standard `c99` does not allow input from `stdin`, but `gcc` and `clang` are happy to do so provided you tell them explicitly that it is a C program (`-x c`). In order to avoid excess compilations, we use `make` (which needs to be `gmake`, Gnu make).

The following requires that the list of replacements be in a file with a `.txt` extension; the cached compiled executable will have the same name with a `.exe` extension. If the makefile were in the current directory with the name `Makefile`, you could invoke it as `make repl` (where `repl` is the name of the replacement file without a text extension), but since that's unlikely to be the case, we'll use a shell function to actually invoke make.

Note that in the following file, the whitespace at the beginning of each line starts with a tab character:

#### substitute.mak

```
.SECONDARY:

%: %.exe
        @$(<D)/$(<F)

%.exe: %.txt
        @{ printf %s\\n "%option 8bit noyywrap nounput" "%%"; \
           sed -r \
              's/((\\\\)*)(\\?)$$/\1\3\3/; #\
               s/((\\\\)*)\\?"/\1\\"/g; #\
               s/^((\\.|[^[:space:]])+)[[:space:]]*(.*)/"\1" {fputs("\3",yyout);}/' \
               "$<"; \
          printf %s\\n "%%" "int main(int argc, char** argv) { return yylex(); }"; \
        } | lex -t | c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -O2 -x c -o "$@" -
```

#### Shell function to invoke the above:

```
substitute() {
  gmake -f/path/to/substitute.mak "${1%.txt}"
}
```

You can invoke the above command with:

```
substitute file
```

where `file` is the name of the replacements file. (The filename must end with `.txt` but you don't have to type the file extension.)

The format of the input file is a series of lines consisting of a target string and a replacement string. The two strings are separated by whitespace. You can use any valid C escape sequence in the strings; you can also <kbd>\</kbd>-escape a space character to include it in the target. If you want to include a literal <kbd>\</kbd>, you'll need to double it.

If you don't want C escape sequences and would prefer to have backslashes not be metacharacters, you can replace the `sed` program with a much simpler one:

```
sed -r 's/([\\"])/\\\1/g' "$<"; \
```

(The `; \` is necessary because of the way `make` works.)

Comment: Since this is only a toy-version of the problem, I am not sure if it will work for the "real thing" as well.

Comment: @DarOrko: `lex` is not a toy; it will handle a very large number of patterns, efficiently and rapidly. Unless there is some aspect of the problem you're not mentioning.

Comment: @DarOrko: I changed the shell function to use a less readable but more efficient `sed` command in case the list of patterns is huge. If it is, I believe this function will be *much* faster than awk or perl based alternatives which do multiple passes over the input string, as well as being more precise when a target is (or starts with) a suffix of another target.

Comment: @rici The `sed` command is missing a closing slash, as in `...yyout);}/'` --- otherwise it is working beautifully

Comment: @rici: I was not referring to the power of lex in writing "toy-version", I rather meant the automatic preference of longer replacement strings. The real problems replacement rules are quite complex.

Comment: @rici: The problem which occurs in substituting "AB" -> "BA", by the two rules "A->B" and "B->A", which is part of the original problem you are referring is in my case not coming up. But anyway I think its better if its circumvented in principle.

Comment: @rici: What do you mean by "tcc"? Is it a windows shell (I operate on a macbook)? How to call this script in order to use "table.txt" and operate it on any string like "aaaaa"?

Comment: @rici: How sensitive would this sed code be to special characters like "$,%,&,-,.,.,,,..." I have all sorts of these in the real problem (mostly in the "from-pattern". To "to-patterns" are latex commands, with some special characters as well (\,{,},^,$,.,..).

Comment: @darorko:  backslashes would need to be doubled although it would be easy to get sed to do that. Tcc is a C compiler with a compile-and-run option; in the original answer you can see an example of using a standard C compiler.

Comment: it is **impossible** to use sed robustly for operations that need to ignore all metacharacters (including RE metacharacters, the sed delimiters like `/` and the backreferences in the replacement text like `&` and `\1`) so don't even try, just use awk since it supports string operations.

Comment: @EdMorton: The `sed` command is used to convert a sequence of non-whitespace (but otherwise arbitrary) characters into something like a C string. (Actually, a lex string, but that's the same format.) So there are no metacharacters to deal with other than what the C standard defines as metacharacters inside a quoted string literal: "any member of the source character set except
the double-quote ", backslash \, or new-line character". Of those, new-line cannot occur because it's whitespace, and the other two only need to have a \ before them. That's well within sed's powers.

Comment: @EdMorton ...in the script here, I actually don't bother with `\\`, since I want to let the user use standard C escape sequences. However, there are a couple of small issues which I should fix, most important being that the word-splitting algorithm doesn't recognize backslash-space as a non-delimiter.

Comment: @rici to be honest I was just replying to DarOko's question about metacharacters and I didn't notice that your sed script wasn't doing the transformation but generating a tool to do the transformation so my apologies for not reading it all first. Having said that, I don't want to start peeling the onion but I will just ask - if `\" 3`, say, existed in the input wouldn't your script output `"\\"" {fputs("3",yyout);}` which I think would be a syntax error? And if you fix that by special-casing `\"` then you need to address `\\"`, and so on...

Comment: @EdMorton: Quite right. That was another of the small issues I should have fixed without being prodded. Fixed now. (The iteration referred to in your last sentence is easily implemented with a Kleene star. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

a) Don't use getline unless you have a very specific need and fully understand all the caveats, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline

b) Don't use regexps when you want strings (yes, this means you cannot use sed).

c) The while loop needs to constantly move beyond the part of the line you've already changed or you could end up in an infinite loop.

You need something like this:

```
$ cat substitute.awk
NR==FNR {
    if (NF==2) {
        strings[++numStrings] = $1
        old2new[$1] = $2
    }
    next
}
{
    for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++) {
        old = strings[stringNr]
        new = old2new[old]
        slength = length(old)
        tail = $0
        $0 = ""
        while ( sstart = index(tail,old) ) {
            $0 = $0 substr(tail,1,sstart-1) new
            tail = substr(tail,sstart+slength)
        }
        $0 = $0 tail
    }
    print
}

$ echo aaa | awk -f substitute.awk table.txt -
3

$ echo aaaa | awk -f substitute.awk table.txt -
31
```

and adding some RE metacharacters to table.txt to show they are treated just like every other character and showing how to run it when the target text is stored in a file instead of being piped:

```
$ cat table.txt
aaa 3
aa 2
a 1
. 7
\ 4
* 9

$ cat foo
a.a\aa*a

$ awk -f substitute.awk table.txt foo
1714291
```

Your new requirement requires a solution like this:

```
$ cat substitute.awk
NR==FNR {
    if (NF==2) {
        strings[++numStrings] = $1
        old2new[$1] = $2
    }
    next
}
{
    delete news
    for (stringNr=1; stringNr<=numStrings; stringNr++) {
        old = strings[stringNr]
        new = old2new[old]
        slength = length(old)
        tail = $0
        $0 = ""
        charPos = 0
        while ( sstart = index(tail,old) ) {
            charPos += sstart
            news[charPos] = new
            $0 = $0 substr(tail,1,sstart-1) RS
            tail = substr(tail,sstart+slength)
        }
        $0 = $0 tail
    }
    numChars = split($0, olds, "")
    $0 = ""
    for (charPos=1; charPos <= numChars; charPos++) {
        $0 = $0 (charPos in news ? news[charPos] : olds[charPos])
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ cat table.txt
1 a
2 b

$ echo "121212" | awk -f substitute.awk table.txt -
ababab
```

Comment: From where to read in the rules and from where the encoded strings, in this program?

Comment: I have tested this awk-scipt and compared with that one above using "getline". For my (extended real problem) inputs they produce the same results ("diff" results in empty output). However, the difference is, that I need to escape ",.+-" and cannot use "$" at least in the from pattern in table.txt when using the getline version. While with yours I can use all these characters but I have to escape ":" in the "table.txt". I am not sure if it is of interest and complies with stackoverflow rules, but in case I could post the files of the real problem.

Comment: Another issue I have realized is that the getline version when used in a pipe sometimes causes "awk command not found". I think this might be related to the caveats you mentioned. So I think I will take over your version.

Comment: Ah more difference: blanklines (at least in the end) in table.txt cause your version to "hang" (enless loop?) while these are apparently not a problem for the getline version.

Comment: I see, ok! I just came about another issue. Given the rules 1. "aa" -> "ab" and 2. "a" -> "1" . I want to get from an input string "aa" the result "ab" and not "1a" (or even "11" which we already excluded by the ordering of the rules). It means processed (result) strings, should not be reprocessed again. How to implement that (I have added that explicitly also to the initial question)? I suppose the results will have to written into a separate array.

Comment: Here is a problem with that, for table.txt (\n is just newline): "1 a\n 2 b" yields for input "121212" -> "aaabbb". So it seems some undesired re-sorting is going on here.

Comment: Sorry, but this script hangs for matches :(

Comment: Sorry, I had deleted a line by accident when editing it (        `slength = length(old)`). Fixed now.

Comment: For simple examples yes, but I am still testing. I ll come back later today.

Comment: @DarOrko How did your testing go?